# angular variable updating, but not refreshing tweet embed code around it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular to cycle through a bunch of tweet id's in an array and render them to the page surrounded by the twitter embed code. The problem is the variable is being updated but the twitter embed isn't being refreshed. Here's what it looks like:

HTML:

```
<!--output the variable for testing (works fine)-->

{{tweets[index].twitterID}} 


<!--twitter embed code wrapped around the above variable -->

<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" width="500" align="center" lang="en">
    <a ng-href="https://twitter.com/user/statuses/{{tweets[index].twitterID}}"></a>
    <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</blockquote>


<!--button to cycle to next tweet-->

<div id="btn" ng-click="increment()">Next</div>
```

Script:

```
$scope.tweets = [] //my tweets json object

$scope.index = 0;
$scope.increment = function () {
     $scope.index = $scope.index + 1;
 }
```

The first tweet is embedding fine, and while the next button does update the variable, the tweet embed isn't changing. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put a $watch statement on the index changing and rendered the whole twitter embed code with the new variable. Seems to have solved the issue.